# How do I access the upper half of the 64-bit address space via /proc/x/mem?

Tags: linux, integer-overflow, seek, procfs

No, I don't have a >18 exabyte file anywhere. I'm trying to read from /proc/self/mem. When I do the following in Python:

```
f.seek(0xfe00001de000007f)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: cannot fit 'int' into an offset-sized integer
```

I also tried using `os.lseek` and got a slightly different error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Finally, I tried doing the seek in two steps:

```
offset = 0xfe00001de000007f
f.seek(offset >> 1)
f.seek(offset >> 1, 1) #seek relative to current position
```

> **EDIT:** There's actually an error in the above code, as `offset >> 1` discards the least significant bit. Which is indeed a 1 in this example. So if it worked, it would actually be seeking to 0xfe00001de000007e. This wasn't the cause of the error I encountered, however. I know this because I tried seeking to 0x7ffffffffffffffe, then doing two relative seeks by one byte each. The first one worked, and the second one gave the error.

But then I just get:

```
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

And I tried doing `f.tell()` after getting that error, and it just gives the same error again.

Further research seems to indicate that Linux simply doesn't support file offsets past 0x7fffffffffffffff. So my question is, how do I access this part of the 64-bit address space via procfs?

Comment: `When I do the following:`  _Where_ do you do you do the following? Doing that in shell would be a syntax error (I think). What is `f`? How is it initialized? What language is this written in? Please create an [MCVE] `how do I access this part of the 64-bit address space via procfs?` Seek is _relative_ to current position. Just seek twice.

Comment: @KamilCuk Oops! That's in a Python shell. Originally my question was specific to Python, then I changed it when I realized the issue wasn't. I'll do an example specific to C, and also put a note in there about Python when I post it. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @KamilCuk: Okay, so seeking twice was actually something I tried, as I mentioned in my question, but when I tried it in C, it actually worked. I'll post that as an answer, unless you want to.

Comment: Looking at the `/proc/x/maps` file it seems that the upper half of the memory area only contains a 4KiB memory block that is equal for all processes: Some wrapper functions needed by the kernel. So there is no need to access the upper half of memory. Maybe `/proc/x/mem` simply cannot access the upper half for this reason.